# After call to a WebService set response value in property to reuse it

Tags: wso2

Following a service call through the mediator call, I try to retrieve a value in the response to reuse it in subsequent calls.
The body is well valued, but against the xpath me never return value.

Extract of the XML file

```
<log description="LogApresAppelALAuthentication" level="full"/>
<property description="Get body response Auth" expression="$body" name="bodyRespAuth" scope="default" type="OM" />
<log>
    <property expression="$ctx:bodyRespAuth" name="bodyRespAuth"/>
</log> 
<property description="Get Token CS" expression="$ctx:bodyRespAuth//AuthenticateUserResult/text()" name="tokenCS" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>  
<log>
    <property expression="$ctx:tokenCS" name="tokenCS"/>
</log>
```

Log :

> ```
> MessageID: urn:uuid:97a99ef0-cfb3-4d14-9013-20ee8bb89e6d, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><AuthenticateUserResponse xmlns="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com"><AuthenticateUserResult>kzE3hcjoG6lYIn6yglLGwYXNivGpCGMDoJWcetPTEj9EiU%2BSGaTqyxZ9azmTc%2BMdGbKcJzCsSAz0epdXkZkP%2BeIazTcvQtu8</AuthenticateUserResult></AuthenticateUserResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
> MessageID: urn:uuid:97a99ef0-cfb3-4d14-9013-20ee8bb89e6d, Direction: request, bodyRespAuth = <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><AuthenticateUserResponse xmlns="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com"><AuthenticateUserResult>kzE3hcjoG6lYIn6yglLGwYXNivGpCGMDoJWcetPTEj9EiU%2BSGaTqyxZ9azmTc%2BMdGbKcJzCsSAz0epdXkZkP%2BeIazTcvQtu8</AuthenticateUserResult></AuthenticateUserResponse></soapenv:Body>
> MessageID: urn:uuid:97a99ef0-cfb3-4d14-9013-20ee8bb89e6d, Direction: request, tokenCS =
> ```

I used several possible combinations for the xpath but each time I have no value in tokencs.
Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution

```
<property description="Get Token CS" expression="$body//*/urn:AuthenticateUserResult/text()" name="tokenCS" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:urn="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com" />
```

I have my value